# Node JS detect if named pipe exists

Tags: node.js, error-handling, connection, named-pipes

I'm trying to use named pipes in my application. The problem is when I try to connect to the named pipe before the server is running, I get the following error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ENOENT \\?\pipe\\testpipe
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1062:14)
```

How can I check if the pipe exists before attempting to connect to it?

**Note:** Wrapping my connect code in a `try-catch` doesn't prevent the error.

Here is my code:

```
var net = require('net');

var addr = '\\\\?\\pipe\\testpipe';
var client = net.createConnection({ path: addr }, function() {
    console.log("Connected");
    client.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log("Recieved: " + data);
    });
    client.on('error', function(){
        console.log(arguments);
    });
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `domain` module prevents a fatal error. The following code can be used to safely run the connect code.

Not what I was hoping for, but the closed solution since there have been no answers.

```
var net = require('net');
var domain = require('domain');

var addr = '\\\\?\\pipe\\testpipe';

var d = domain.create();
d.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});

d.run(function() {
    var client = net.createConnection({ path: addr }, function() {
        console.log("Connected");
        client.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log("Recieved: " + data);
        });
        client.on('error', function(){
            console.log(arguments);
        });
    }.bind(this));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

make the socket, then listen for an `error` event, *then* call `connect` and it won't be thrown: https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_error_1